# Set low priority for long mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

guys!

I have a long query which executes 1-2 times at night. This query excracts data only (by operator find) and works about 15-20 minutes.

When this query executing mongodb can't proccess other queries.

Is it impossible to set low priority to query?

Answer (score 2):

It would take some doing, but the best way to execute a long-running query would be against a hidden (read only) replica-set.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/#replica-set-hidden-members

As a hidden replica set, your clients won't hit it in the standard replica set rotation. As it says here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/ you can set your read preference to secondary to force it off of your primary db.